# Why is 上 used in 商業上の目的で?

Tags: suffixes

From the definition of 広告 in [大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/72817/meaning/m0u/%E5%BA%83%E5%91%8A/):

> **商業上の目的で**、商品やサービス、事業などの情報を積極的に世間に広く宣伝すること。また、そのための文書や放送など。「―を載せる」「新製品を―する」「募集―」

I wonder why they use 上 in 商業上の目的で. Why not just 商業の目的で?

Comment: 上 here means "related to".  From the perspective of English, it may seem a bit unnecessary because either way 商業上 or  商業 would be translated as "commerce".

Comment: Related:  [What does it mean to be “over a law”?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4329/78)

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr.istrasci. I had been always thinking of 上 as "ue" so I kind of "why it's used here?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would need to be 「[商業上]{しょうぎょうじょう}の[目的]{もくてき}で」 with 「上」 to mean "***for commercial purposes***".

「商業の目的」 sounds too "grandiose" to my Japanese ear.  That is like saying "**The Purpose of Commerce**" in a much more philosophical sense.

If one were talking about advertisement or its place in commerce as an everyday kind of phenomenon, 「商業**上**の目的」 would sound much more natural and suitable.

Comment: l'électeurさん、どうもありがとうございました。