# Question about meaning of words 立場上 and 身分上

Tags: words

I read the definition of 義務 because I found the word **義務**教育:

> 人が人として，あるいは**立場上**，**身分上**当然しなければならないこと

I understand the definition as "Thing that a person has to do" but I can't find the meanings of 立場上 and 身分上, so my understanding is excluding those parts. What is the 上 meaning in these words? Is it the 上-definition:

> Noun, Noun which may take the genitive case particle 'no', Adverb (fukushi), Noun, used as a **suffix**: 1. above; up; over; elder (e.g. daughter)(jisho)

But then I don't understand how the sentence makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ～上【じょう】 is a suffix that forms an adverb/no-adjective meaning "～-wise", "in terms of ～" or "from the viewpoint of ～".

- [I need help analyzing the phrase 発音上の](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61291/5010)
- [What does it mean to be "over a law"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4329/5010)
- [Why isn't a large amount of money a good enough reason to kill someone?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3174/5010)

For example:

- 金銭上: in terms of money; financially
- 文法上: grammar-wise; grammatically
- 教育上: from an educational point of view; educationally
- 法律上: according to the law; legally speaking
- 計算上: mathematically speaking; if my calculation is correct

立場 is "standpoint", and 身分 is "social status/position". 立場 is something that can change depending on the situation, while 身分 is something that is fixed for a long time (sometimes for the entire life).

In your sentence, I think 上 can be translated like:

> 立場**上**、身分**上**当然しなければならないこと
> a thing one must naturally do **{based on | in accord with}** his/her position

Comment: How does it compare with 的に?

Comment: @JimmyYang Not very different, but 上 is stiffer, and preferred in academic/legal contexts.

Comment: @JimmyYang 歴史上の means "in history" or "historical", whereas 歴史的な usually means "epoch-making" or "historic", so they are not always interchangeable. Not sure if there's a general rule...